# Crisp Set QCA- only getting 1's, 0.5's or 0s for inclusion

Tags: r, boolean, truthtable

I'm doing some crisp set QCA using the QCA R package, I've generated the truthtable, but results only showing inclusion of 1 or 0 or 0.5, are there any ideas of why this might be?

I have done

```
tt_df <- truthTable(df, outcome= "Engage", complete= TRUE, show.cases = TRUE, sort.by = "incl")
```

but for some reason the inclusion scores are all very similar, when generally there should be decimal points.